# Translation of a mathematical summation into code

Tags: python, docplex

I'm playing with docplex on Python and I'm facing some difficulties.
I wanto to code the [Mathematical expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GeEU.png)
attached in the image as constraints, but it is quite hard for me. I know that t and T are fixed values.
I coded the first constraint without considering `v1≠v`, I don't know if it is even possible to add it.
For the second constraint I tried to write a code but I'm pretty confident it is wrong because it does not consider the part of the summation which says
**f<sub>v,v1</sub>=i**

My code is:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
mdl = Model('Optimization model')

#For matrix G, columns represent v, rows represent t
G = ((0, 2, 2, 1),
     (1, 0, 5, 4),
     (2, 5, 0, 3),
     (3, 0, 5, 4),
     (4, 5, 0, 7),
     (5, 6, 4, 0))

#For matrix f, rows represent v and columns represent v1 (it is a time matrix, for travelling from v to v1)
f = ((0, 1, 2, 1),
    (1, 0, 2, 1),
    (2, 2, 0, 2),
    (1, 1, 2, 0))

E = (2, 1, 1, 0)

t=2  # t is given
T=len(G)
V=len(E)

# Define the variable
X = mdl.integer_var_matrix(V, V, lb=0, name="X")

# Define the constraints
Constraint1 = mdl.add_constraints([sum(x[v,v1] for v1 in range(V) if v != v1) <= E[v] for v in range(V)])

Constraint2 = mdl.add_constraints([sum(x[v,v1] for v1 in range(V)) <= G[v,t+i] for v in range(V) for i in range(T-t)])
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Edit:

- I added the answer I received for the first constraint and it works.
- I made the code more readable and added the `import` part.
- For the second constraint I'm still struggling. I tried adding the **f<sub>v,v1</sub>=i** part to the code but without success. Any help is more than welcome!

Edit1:
I solved the second constraint as follow, but not sure if it is really right:

```
for i in range(T-t):
    for v in range(V): 
        temp = (sum(x[v1,v] for v1 in range(V) if (i+1) == f[v1][v]))
        mdl.add_constraint(temp <= G[t+i][v])
```

Answer (score 0):

> I coded the first constraint without considering v'≠v, I don't know if it is even possible to add it

For this, just change

```
sum(x[v,v1] for v1 in range(V))
```

to

```
sum(x[v,v1] for v1 in range(V) if v != v1)
```

(assuming `v'` is `v1` in your code).

> For the second constraint I tried to write a code but I'm pretty confident it is wrong because it does not consider the part of the summation which says `f_v_v'=i`

You should be able to add a similar `if` clause to the second generator expression. There is nothing in your formulas that indicate where `f_v_v'` comes from, so I can't give any exact code.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and excellent advice!

f_v_v' is coming from the f matrix, in Excel I would use something like a vlookup function but here I really don't know how to call specific value of f in the constraint code

Comment: @Fab Probably just `f[v][v']` or something similar. If you are unfamiliar with this syntax, I suggest you read more about lists and tuples in Python.